# unresolved import sc_rpc::Metadata

Tags: frontier

i try to import fc-rpc on fronter.
but got some error message

```shell
Compiling fc-rpc v2.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git#9d4ccba8)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `sc_rpc::Metadata`
  --> /home/kula/.cargo/git/checkouts/frontier-b4643f17507d3282/9d4ccba/client/rpc/src/eth_pubsub.rs:38:5
   |
38 | use sc_rpc::Metadata;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Metadata` in the root

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `fc-rpc` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

what's wrong with this?

my rust toolcain

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly"
components = [ "rustfmt", "clippy" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
profile = "minimal"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

In a newer release of the sc-rpc, the Metadata struct was removed. Unfortunately, fc-rpc (Frontier's rpc pallet) is not yet compatible with this change.

The simplest fix right now is to run `cargo update -p <the-imported-pallet> --precise 1e0807fb477b21edd373eb88778336d5ff23d3a7`

This will set the pallet you are importing to use the commit `1e0807fb477b21edd373eb88778336d5ff23d3a7`. This commit uses a compatible version of sc-rpc.

Unfortunately, adding `rev = 1e0807fb477b21edd373eb88778336d5ff23d3a7` into your Cargo.toml will not work. Cargo has a [bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10256) right now that duplicates dependencies (with the exact same code, Cargo just does not recognize it).